# Using two np.linspace, how to fill 2D array with complex values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I'm trying to fill a 2D array with `complex(x,y)`, where `x` and `y` are from two two arrays:

```
xstep = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, Nx)
ystep = np.linspace(ymin, ymax, Ny)
```

However I can't figure out how to "spread" these values out on a 2D array.

So far my attempts are not really working out. I was hoping for something along the lines of:

```
result = np.array(xstep + (1j * ystep))
```

Maybe something from `fromfunction`, `meshgrid` or `full`, but I can't quite make it work.

As an example, say I do this:

```
xstep = np.linspace(0, 1, 2)  # array([0., 1.])
ystep = np.linspace(0, 1, 3)  # array([0. , 0.5, 1. ])
```

I'm trying to construct an answer:

```
array([
[0+0j, 0+0.5j, 0+1j],
[1+0j, 1+0.5j, 1+1j]
])
```

Note that I am not married to the `linspace`, so any quicker method would also do, it is just my natural starting point for creating this array, being new to Numpy.

Answer (score 4):

```
In [4]: xstep = np.linspace(0, 1, 2)

In [5]: ystep = np.linspace(0, 1, 3)

In [6]: xstep[:, None] + 1j*ystep
Out[6]: 
array([[0.+0.j , 0.+0.5j, 0.+1.j ],
       [1.+0.j , 1.+0.5j, 1.+1.j ]])
```

---

`xstep[:, None]` is equivalent to `xstep[:, np.newaxis]` and its purpose is to add a new axis to `xstep` *on the right*. Thus, `xstep[:, None]` is a 2D array of shape `(2, 1)`.

```
In [19]: xstep[:, None].shape
Out[19]: (2, 1)
```

`xstep[:, None] + 1j*ystep` is thus the sum of a 2D array of shape `(2, 1)` and a 1D array of shape `(3,)`.

[NumPy broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) resolves this apparent shape conflict by automatically adding new axes (of length 1) *on the left*. So, by NumPy broadcasting rules, `1j*ystep` is promoted to an array of shape `(1, 3)`. 
(Notice that `xstep[:, None]` is required to explicitly add new axes on the right, but broadcasting will automatically add axes on the left. This is why `1j*ystep[None, :]` was unnecessary though valid.)

Broadcasting further promotes both arrays to the common shape `(2, 3)` (but in a memory-efficient way, without copying the data). The values along the axes of length 1 are broadcasted repeatedly:

```
In [15]: X, Y = np.broadcast_arrays(xstep[:, None], 1j*ystep)

In [16]: X
Out[16]: 
array([[0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1.]])

In [17]: Y
Out[17]: 
array([[0.+0.j , 0.+0.5j, 0.+1.j ],
       [0.+0.j , 0.+0.5j, 0.+1.j ]])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `np.ogrid` with imaginary "step" to obtain linspace semantics:

```
y, x = np.ogrid[0:1:2j, 0:1:3j]                                                                               
y + 1j*x
# array([[0.+0.j , 0.+0.5j, 0.+1.j ],                                                                                 
#        [1.+0.j , 1.+0.5j, 1.+1.j ]])
```

Here the `ogrid` line means make an open 2D grid. axis 0: 0 to 1, 2 steps, axis 1: 0 to 1, 3 steps. The type of the slice "step" acts as a switch, if it is imaginary (in fact anything of complex type) its absolute value is taken and the expression is treated like a linspace. Otherwise range semantics apply.

The return values

```
y, x
# (array([[0.],                                                                                                       
#         [1.]]), array([[0. , 0.5, 1. ]]))
```

are "broadcast ready", so in the example we can simply add them and obtain a full 2D grid.

If we allow ourselves an imaginary "stop" parameter in the second slice (which only works with linspace semantics, so depending on your style you may prefer to avoid it) this can be condensed to one line:

```
sum(np.ogrid[0:1:2j, 0:1j:3j])
# array([[0.+0.j , 0.+0.5j, 0.+1.j ],
#        [1.+0.j , 1.+0.5j, 1.+1.j ]])
```

A similar but potentially more performant method would be preallocation and then broadcasting:

```
out = np.empty((y.size, x.size), complex)
out.real[...], out.imag[...] = y, x
out
# array([[0.+0.j , 0.+0.5j, 0.+1.j ],
#        [1.+0.j , 1.+0.5j, 1.+1.j ]])
```

And another one using outer sum:

```
np.add.outer(np.linspace(0,1,2), np.linspace(0,1j,3))
# array([[0.+0.j , 0.+0.5j, 0.+1.j ],
#        [1.+0.j , 1.+0.5j, 1.+1.j ]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `reshape(-1,1)` for `xstep` as:

```
xstep = np.linspace(0, 1, 2)  # array([0., 1.])
ystep = np.linspace(0, 1, 3)  # array([0. , 0.5, 1. ])

result = np.array(xstep.reshape(-1,1) + (1j * ystep))

result

array([[0.+0.j , 0.+0.5j, 0.+1.j ],
       [1.+0.j , 1.+0.5j, 1.+1.j ]])
```